# MySQL query doesn't show all the records correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The query am running against my database to get the 3 records order it by Random. The problem is that sometimes it shows all 3 records sometimes it only shows 2, 1 and other times its just blank. In the database I have around 28 records.

**What I have tried**

1. I have tried without **LIMIT** - Problem Same
2. I have echoed out **$suggested_profile_id** found all 3 records coming out.

**This is the query that gets the records LIMIT it by 3**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_status='activated' ORDER BY RAND() DESC LIMIT 3";
  $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
   if($db->NUM_ROWS() > 0){
     $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT();
?>
```

**This is the code that runs and gets all 3 records in a loop.**

```
<!-- Suggested Friends -->
    <div class="col-md-0 media-body">
    <?php
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $member_id = $row->member_id;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE profile_id='$member_id' LIMIT 1";
        $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
        $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT();
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $suggested_profile_id = $row->profile_id;
            $suggested_profile_photo = $row->profile_photo;
            $suggested_profile_username = $row->profile_username;
            $suggested_profile_name = $row->profile_name;
                if(
                    $suggested_profile_id != GET_SESSION_ID_VALUE(ENCRYPTION_KEY)&&
                    !is_in_ARRAY($make_string_to_ARRAY, $suggested_profile_id) 
                ){
    ?>
    <div class="row margin0">
      <div class="col-md-4 pad0">
        <a href="/<?php echo $suggested_profile_username; ?>" title="<?php echo $suggested_friends_profile_name; ?>" >
        <?php
          global $suggested_friends_profile_id;
          $member_dir = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . "/members/" . $suggested_profile_id ."/smalll_" . $suggested_profile_photo;
          if(file_exists($member_dir)){
        ?>
          <img alt="<?php echo $suggested_profile_name; ?>" title="<?php echo $suggested_profile_name; ?>" src="/members/<?php echo $suggested_profile_id; ?>/smalll_<?php echo $suggested_profile_photo; ?>" width="50" height="50">
        <?php   
          } else {
        ?>
          <img alt="<?php echo $suggested_profile_name; ?>" title="<?php echo $suggested_profile_name; ?>" src="/assets/images/default.jpg" width="50" height="50">
        <?php   
          }
        ?>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 pad0">
        <a href="<?php echo $suggested_profile_username; ?>" class="bold welcome-name"><?php echo $suggested_profile_name; ?></a>
        <span class="f12 gray">271 Mutual Friends</span>
        <a href="#" class="welcome-name">Add as friend</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <?php
                }
            }           
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    <!-- ** Suggested Friends -->
```

What am I missing? Is there any alternative way I can achieve this...thanks!

Comment: check, out of 28 records how many records have `member_status='activated'`

Comment: @krishna there are 22 active records

Comment: in the first query you have `DESC LIMIT 3` so remove that `LIMIT 3`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query. Pasting it directly into the command line will prove this. So your problem is your code, but I'm not going through all that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're overwriting your `$rows` variable within the inner select.

```
foreach($rows as $row){ // <-- first $rows / $row
    $member_id = $row->member_id;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE profile_id='$member_id' LIMIT 1";
    $query = $db->SELECT($sql);
    $rows = $db->FETCH_OBJECT(); <-- $rows overwritten
    foreach($rows as $row){
```

Break your display from your application logic and you won't have such a hard time debugging this kind of thing.  Besides, you have a lot of duplicated code and that makes things hard to manage as well as being hard to debug.

Further, you wouldn't have this problem if you ran one query: `SELECT * FROM members JOIN  profile ON members.member_id = profile.profile_id` and not only does your code get simpler and your double-foreach loop problem disappear, but your database access will also be a lot more efficient.

Comment: great!  I hope you'll consider accepting the answer, if it's what you were looking for.